# Show or Hide HTML Columns Table based on Checkboxes Data, Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, checkbox

I have an HTML table with the days of a week

```
|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|
|data  |data   |----     |----    |----  |----    |---   |
```

And have a Relation, Route-Client, and I whant to show(or not show) the columns days respect the value 1 from among a checkboxes from the Table Route. I save the checkboxes data with 0 and 1, working day 1, free day 0, and I'm extracting those 0 and 1 with this method:

Inside a Form::open()

```
<td>Route:</td>
    <select id="day" name="day" onchange="showDays()">
        @foreach($route as $ro)
        <option value="{{ $ro['id'] .','. $ro['monday'] .','. $ro['tuesday'] .','. $ro['wednesday'] .','. $ro['thursday'] .','. $ro['friday'] .','. $ro['saturday'] .','. $ro['sunday'] }}">
            {{ $ro['name'] }} 
        </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <input id="id_route" type=hidden name="id_route">
```

Javascript Method

```
 function showDays() {

    var day = $("#day").val();
    alert(day);

    var days= day.slice(-13);
    alert(days);

    //I pass the respective binary number to the respective day

    var monday= document.getElementById("monday");
    monday= day.slice(-13,-12);
    $("#monday").val(monday); //don't know if this can help me in other javascript function
    alert(monday);

    var tuesday= document.getElementById("tuesday");
    tuesday= day.slice(-11,-10);
    $("#tuesday").val(tuesday);
    alert(tuesday);

    var wednesday= document.getElementById("wednesday");
    wednesday= day.slice(-9,-8);
    $("#wednesday").val(wednesday);
    alert(wednesday);

    var thursday= document.getElementById("thursday");
    thursday= day.slice(-7,-6);
    $("#thursday").val(thursday);
    alert(thursday);

    var friday= document.getElementById("friday");
    friday= day.slice(-5,-4);
    $("#friday").val(friday);
    alert(friday);

    var saturday= document.getElementById("saturday");
    saturday= day.slice(-3,-2);
    $("#saturday").val(saturday);
    alert(saturday);

    var sunday= document.getElementById("sunday");
    sunday= day.slice(-1);
    $("#sunday").val(sunday);
    alert(sunday);

}
```

Inside my HTML table:

```
<tr><!--I been thinking on doing something like this -->
    <th <a id="monday" onchange="showDays()" value="{{$route['monday']}}">MONDAY</th>
    <th <a id="tuesday" onchange="showDays()" value="{{$route['tuesday']}}">TUESDAY</th>
    <th <a id="wednesday" onchange="showDays()" value="{{$route['wednesday']}}">WEDNESDAY</th>
    <th <a id="thursday" onchange="showDays()"value="{{$route['thursday']}}">THURSDAY</th>
    <th <a id="friday" onchange="showDays()" value="{{$route['friday']}}">FRIDAY</th>
    <th <a id="saturday" onchange="showDays()" value="{{$route['saturday']}}">SATURDAY</th>
    <th <a id="sunday" onchange="showDays()" value="{{$route['sunday']}}">SUNDAY</th>
</tr>

@foreach($client as $ct)
<tr> <!--In this moment I just fill all the days with all the clients, but the idea is to fill the days respect the clients assigned by that day-->
    <td id="mondayTD">{{ $ct->client_name }}</td> 
    <td id="tuesdayTD">{{ $ct->client_name }}</td>
    <td id="wednesdayTD">{{ $ct->client_name }}</td>
    <td id="thursdayTD">{{ $ct->client_name }}</td>
    <td id="fridayTD">{{ $ct->client_name }}</td>
    <td id="saturdayTD">{{ $ct->client_name }}</td>
    <td id="sundayTD">{{ $ct->client_name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

If I do it like this I get on the Headers of the table the numbers 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 which are the binary values of the last Route created on my DB(for the moment don't know how to make change those values, just show the last created).

I need respect the values 1 or 0 received on my th to decide if show the column or not show it, but I don't know how to do that, if someone can help me I will be really grateful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a php page to print the table. This will print the table based on the values of the checkbox, passed by POST. All you have to do then is call this page using ajax and put the response inside the div you want.

Using jQuery and .post(), this becomes pretty simple:

```
$.post( "tablepage.php", { monday: "1", tuesday: "0" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    $( "#div" ).html(data);
  });
```

This should be part of a function fired every time checkboxes are changed. tablepage.php will receive the values for days by post, like `$_POST['monday']`. Use them to generate the table. The `$( "#divname" ).html(data);` code pass the output of the php script to the div.